# Rendering Alpha Video with Compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, video

I want to render a video, it contains some glass text animation. I want to export transparency, but also keeping the glare and streaks that I added in Compositing.

How do I do this? Seems to be rendering only Alpha EXR with no Compositing whatsoever.

[image: Compositing Nodes]

Comment: Glare is made of light, it needs to be added to an image not mixed with it, so you cannot really make a meaningful mask for it.  You should composite what you want with masks, but then add(in a mathematical sense - the pixel color values are added) light effects like glare or glow.  Also keep in mind that color space should be linear while compositing, preferably higher bit depth than what you are going to save the result to.